# Breakpoints aren't working as expected

Tags: html, css, less, breakpoints

I'm trying to understand how I can stop the breakpoint knocking the "contact" menu item down onto the next line. Here's the [link to the page](http://burgopak.com/).

I want to make the hamburger appear instead of knocking the contact menu item onto the next page which happens when the page is less than 1065px.

Using less and have variables set up:

**Less variables:**

```
@mobile: 800px;
@tablet: 900px;
@desktop: 1300px;

@grid-columns: 12;
@grid-gutter-width: @space;

@grid-float-breakpoint: @mobile;
@grid-float-breakpoint-max: (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1);
```

**HTML Nav**

```
<nav class="container lg nav">
<div class="hamburger-wrap js-toggle-menu">
    Menu
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
</div>
<a href="/" class="logo fl">{{ site_name }}</a>
<span class="panel">

{{ nav from="/" include_home="false" include_entries="true" exclude_from_navigation:isnt="true" }}
    {{ if has_entries }}
        <span class="dropdown js-dropdown">
            <span class="dropdown-trigger {{ if is_current or is_parent }}active{{ /if }}">{{ tag:nav_title or title }}</span>
            <span class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="{{ url }}">All</a>
                {{ *recursive children* }}
            </span>
        </span>
    {{ else }}
    <a {{ if is_current or is_parent }} class="active"{{ /if }} href="{{ page_link or url_link or get:url }}" {{ if target }}target="_blank"{{ /if }}">
        {{ tag:nav_title or title }}
    </a>
    {{ /if }}
{{ /nav }}

        </span>
```

Comment: You should give your navigation items a fixed width, to calculate your breakpoints properly. Otherwise you need JavaScript to calculate the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hamburger menu is set to be visible using your `@tablet` resolution on the media query min value. I got this by inspecting your page:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .nav .hamburger-wrap {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 22px;
        right: 30px;
        bottom: auto;
        left: auto;
        z-index: 2;
        padding-right: 25px;
        line-height: 1;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
}
```

That means that on any window size larger than 900px the hamburger will be hidden and the regular desktop menu will be visible - rendering it on two lines when there's not enough room, as you noticed.

Changing your less file to show it using the `@desktop` variable will show the hamburger for screens up to 1300px wide. It should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Fernanda but I tried that and all it does is make the nav disappear when the screen is larger than 1300px. I'm editing this locally. But after I inspect the code it says its `@media (min-width: 1300px)` not what you say.

Comment: @Jamie Make sure you're using the same media query for both the regular nav _and_ the hamburger menu. otherwise you will have a wide gap between their hidden/visible states.

Comment: Maybe you should clear your browser cache with CTRL+F5 or something else.

Comment: I'm on a Mac so I have to use cmd + R to force refresh. When I did your solution worked @FernandaParisi thank you :).